# How can I use both page line functions and scripts function in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

how can i use both the page level function and script file factory, service etc in AngularJs.

> Html code:-

```
<div ng-app="mainApp">
        <div class="row" ng-controller="myController">
            <p><b>Message From Service: </b>{{serviceMsg}}</p>
            <p><b>Message From Factory: </b>{{factoryMsg}}</p>
            <p><b>Message From Provider:</b>{{providerMsg}}</p>
        </div>

        <div class="row" ng-controller="CalcController">
            <p>Enter a number: <input type="number" ng-change="myFunc()" ng-model="number" /></p>
            <button ng-click="square()">X<sup>2</sup></button>
            <p>Result: {{result}}</p>
        </div>

        <div class="row" ng-controller="TestController">
            <p>Results:{{Results}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

> Script code:-

```
<script>
        angular.element(document).ready(function () {
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['mainApp']);
        });

        var app = angular.module("mainApp", []);
        app.controller('TestController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.Results = '5';
        });
    </script>

    <script src="angularjs/main.js"></script>
```

if i run main.js block alone output showing fine, but if i run both the page level TestController and main.js function then error raising

> Error:

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.1/ng/areq?p0=TestController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
```

so how could i run both the page level controller and outside script file function in AngularJS function.. pls share your experience..

Comment: Why you want to run inline and script function both when only script is working fine for you?

Comment: yes, your question correct, but if i'm creating common function to reuse like inherit concept then i will code other than that script file that's why

Comment: for common insert/update/delete/approve/retrieve kind of work can done in common script then normal function can create with easy of work that's why, now i hope u ll understand

Comment: I think you should not use this approach. Can you elaborate more @Ethirajram ? I cant understand what you are trying to achieve. A plunkr example would be the best way to explain your business scenario

Comment: see my Plunker -- https://embed.plnkr.co/kDowdQgbIpQjrESCktrP/

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

[Check this plunkr for your example fix](https://plnkr.co/edit/ydTIu1oIpXQ0iq2s6XwF?p=preview)

Please note the change in sequence of `<script>` tag and the way `angular.module("mainApp").controller('TestController',` is called

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script>
    angular.module("mainApp")
    .controller('TestController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.Results = 5;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thank so much it have been work, without [] and script file reference has to above the inline function, once again thank you so much

Comment: @Ethirajram Plz mark it as an answer if it helped you